# PowerShell exporting csv results with columns

Tags: powershell, csv

i just need to have an csv as output with the name of the servers in one column and the result of the command in the second column. I cannot use the export-csv cmdlet because im using a old version of PS. Thank you very much for your help!

```
$servers = Get-Content -path .\Server_List.txt

ForEach ($server in $servers)
{
(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System).EnableLUA
}
Out-File UAC_audit_results.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So then use a string formatter in the loop and out-file with -append. Or don't use a ForEach($server in $servers) and pipe it all to out-file, but you can't easily pipe a foreach loop as you have it constructed. Just make sure to add a header line first.

```
$servers = Get-Content -path .\Server_List.txt
"Server,Results"|Out-File UAC_audit_results.csv
ForEach ($server in $servers)
{
    $RegProp = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System).EnableLUA
    "{0},{1}" -f $server, $RegProp|Out-File UAC_audit_results.csv -append
}
```

Or, (what I think is better), pipe it:

```
"Server,Results"|Out-File UAC_audit_results.csv
Get-Content -path .\Server_List.txt |%{"{0},{1}" -f $_, (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System |select -expand EnableLUA)}|Out-File UAC_audit_results.csv -append
```

Comment: Something is wrong. I have as return all servers with code 0 (there are some servers that has UAC enabled)

Comment: That has nothing to do with the file output, that has to do with the fact that you are querying the local machine's registry each time. You never reference another machine when you do the Get-ItemProperty call, it's always done on the local machine. You didn't ask for help with querying remote registries, if you need help with that please open a new question for that. If this resolved the question of outputting a CSV as desired please mark the answer as accepted and proceed with opening a new question with your updated code and issue.